# Pourquoi le subjonctif futur n'existe-t-il pas — ou plus — en français ?

Tags: histoire, temps-grammatical, subjonctif

**Il existait en latin**, et a survécu en espagnol et en portugais. Ce n'est donc pas une conception absurde.

*Mais son absence implique un manque de logique dans l'accord des temps.*

Présent : "Je souhaite que notre forum accroisse son audience" : *parfaitement logique*.

Passé : "En découvrant par hasard ce forum il y a un mois, je souhaitai immédiatement qu'il accrût son audience" : *parfaitement logique* encore (mais dans l'usage, qui ne l'est pas et donc complique les choses, on n'utilise ni passé simple, ni imparfait du subjonctif).

Futur : "Après quelques réformes, je souhaiterai qu'il **???** son audience dans l'avenir". *Lacune illogique*, qui me contraint, en pratique, à mettre un conditionnel ( ... je souhaiterais qu'il accrût ... ) — alors que la phrase précédente était inconditionnelle, donc de sens différent voire opposé — ou à utiliser une tournure entièrement différente.

**Mes questions sont donc** :

1. A-t-il jamais existé ? Sinon, pourquoi (parce que le latin était mieux implanté dans la péninsule Ibérique, et plus purement ?).
2. Si oui, quelles en sont les traces, et quand a-t-il disparu ?

Comment: En fait, c'est plutôt le portugais (et dans une moindre mesure l'espagnol) qui sont les exceptions : le subjonctif futur a disparu aussi en italien et en roumain. L'indicatif futur a aussi [subi des transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_tense#Latin_and_Romance) dès le bas latin. Je pense que cette question aurait plus de chances d'avoir une réponse sur [linguistics.se], généralisée aux langues romanes.

Comment: Est-il logique de faire un souhait au futur ? Le moment où tu fais ce souhait est le présent et l'objet de ce souhait se déroule "dans l'avenir". Je ne vois pas de lacune dans ce cas. Pourrais-tu trouver un exemple dans lequel le subjonctif futur serait nécessaire ?

Comment: D'accord avec sinsedrix sur ce point : je ne trouve pas non plus que l'expressivité de notre langue soit en défaut sur ce point précis, ou bien je ne parviens pas à saisir ton example...

Comment: en patois baste + que + verbe aux subjonctif, exprime le doute (présent) souhait (futur ),regret ( passé), je conviens que le futur de l'indicatif l'a remplacé , mais c'est illogique

Comment: Je ne pense pas que *il existait en latin*.

Answer (score 3):

Il n'existe pas en français... sauf chez Les Inconnus : « il faut que tu arriveras à laminer tes rancoeurs dialectiques »…

Comment: ++1! lol! Yessss! Trop fort! Noter qu'il soufre toutefois d'une concurrence avec le futur proche. Lu chez... Benzéma... : *"Il faut que je vais aller voir le juge"*... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

*" Dans l'exemple que vous donnez pour le futur, en fait je n'utiliserais pas « je souhaiterai » mais « je souhaiterais ». Le conditionnel est lié au futur."*

Il est vrai que le subjonctif, mode n'ayant pas de valeur temporelle, devient simultané du moment indiqué par le verbe introducteur, mais dans les deux exemples que vous donnez, que vous employiez le futur "souhaiterai" ou le conditionnel "souhaiterais", ces deux temps ne sont pas employés avec une valeur temporelle (qui les ferait s'inscrire clairement dans le futur), mais avec une valeur modale d'atténuation : le verbe pourrait être au présent, mais pour atténuer son souhait, le locuteur fait semblant de le repousser dans le futur ou de ne le rendre que probable. Ces formes ne sont pas réellement ancrées dans une temporalité futur. Alors que dans d'autres phrases où, cette fois, le futur est vraiment employé avec une valeur temporelle, par exemple *"Quoi que tu ___ l'an prochain, j'attendrai ton retour"* (on mettra "quoi que tu fasses" avec un subjonctif présent), un subjonctif futur serait en effet vraiment nécessaire. Je regrette qu'il n'en existe pas en français...

Answer (score 1):

Comme le fait remarquer Gilles, ce sont l'espagnol et le portugais qui sont des particularités.
En fait je pense que la raison pour laquelle nous n'avons pas de subjonctif futur c'est que dans la plupart des cas l'expression du futur se trouve exprimée dans le verbe introducteur, la plupart du temps avec un subjonctif. Dans l'exemple que vous donnez pour le futur, en fait je n'utiliserais pas « *je souhaiterai* » mais « *je souhaiterais* ». Le conditionnel est lié au futur. Par conséquent, le verbe au subjonctif devient simultané du moment indiqué par le verbe introducteur. Il est donc logique d'utiliser un présent du subjonctif. Le présent n'est pas relatif au moment actuel mais à la simultanéité dans le futur.

Answer (score 1):

En latin, il n'y a pas de conditionnel dont la fonction est prise dans le subjonctif imparfait (amarem).
Je suis d'accord que pour la concordance des temps, il serait pratique d'avoir un subjonctif futur, de même par exemple qu'un participe futur (actif), comme "moriturus" en latin.

Answer (score 0):

Je vous invite à lire l'intéressante étude de Gustave Guillaume à propos de l'architectonique verbale en indo-européen.
Aucun subjonctif pour les temps futur, ni futur simple ni antérieur.
Ce sont des éventuels!

Comment: Une référence précise serait un plus. Est-ce qu'il s'agit de [Temps et verbe. Théorie des aspects, des modes et des temps suivi de L'architectonique du temps dans les langues classiques](http://www.worldcat.org/title/temps-et-verbe-theorie-des-aspects-des-modes-et-des-temps-suivi-de-larchitectonique-du-temps-dans-les-langues-classiques/oclc/11619961&referer=brief_results) ?